# You must call the_content function in the current template when Edit a blog page

Tags: wordpress

When editing a blog page with Elementor Pro, but I only see the Elementor option available; I am using **BeTheme**

[image]

and when editing with Elementor, I have this error:

[image]

*"Sorry, the content area was not found in your page. You must call
the_content function in the current template, in order for Elementor to work on this page.”*

Comment: Wich theme you are using?

Comment: There are many(like me) who don't understand the language of the text shown in your screenshot. So I would suggest posting a translated text beneath your images.

Comment: @enPeris did you checked [elementor help](https://elementor.com/help/the-content-area-was-not-found-error/).

Comment: Yes I did with no success

Comment: @enPeris did you edit any template if yes try reverting it to previous version after taking backup of template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case 1:**

> When editing a blog page with Elementor Pro,

Does this mean you are trying to edit the page which is set as `Posts` page in `Reading Settings`?

You can't edit the page with Elementor. It can be edited by Elementor Pro’s Theme Builder function only as it is described [here](https://elementor.com/help/create-archive-template/).

[image]

**Case 2:**
I read you are using **BeTheme**. Do you use a custom child theme and set a custom page template for the page?
If this is the case, please check the template file, if it has `the_content()` function.